# Sketch + Xcode Launch Image

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

I'm trying to insert a launch image in my Xcode project.
I have created the image with Sketch 3 and exported in normal, @2x and @3x format, i have also checked the dimensions required for the launch images [here](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html) and they match, but apparently XCode doesn't want me to insert them, because keeps showing me this error for every image:

[image]

Are Sketch 3 sizes wrong? What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size is correct - are you dragging it to the appropriate bucket on your images library? Also could be the space in the filename? Try dragging your images explicitly onto the proper spot in your launch image.

If you don't have a launch image yet on your Images.xcassets, you can right-click and select "New launch image", which will generate this: http://prntscr.com/7qrom9

Comment: I was completely dumb. I completely forgot that i need also iPhone 5, and 6p image sizes and not only 6 1x 2x and 3x

Comment: Nice! Yea I never remember what sizes I need. Easiest way for me is to make that blank launch image and fill in the blanks. Have fun!